# Drupal 7 : How to show specific block in a particular view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to display particular block on view page. I have added list to **show specific view in a particular block** as `<viewpagename>`, but it is not working. How can I show a particular block on a particular view page in Drupal 7?

Comment: I get only one solution. If there any other solution exists in simple way
<?php
$url = request_uri();
if (strpos($url, "viewtest")) {
return TRUE;
}
?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long time I didn't touch Drupal, however, if I remember right, after you choose a path for your view, you can add that path to the settings of the block.

so if the view is available on /view-page, add to the block setting "view-page" in the "include" section.

Comment: I just tried 
Block >> configure >> Only the listed pages >> added <view-page> But its not working :(

Comment: That suppose to work. if it doesn't something isn't working somewhere else. make sure the view is available, make sure the block is working (try putting it everywhere for the test)...

Comment: Sure thing :) It would be nice if after you find the solution you'll add it, even just to fill my curiosity...

Comment: In one way i have already done using php function in my first comment and straight way i will find and will post here.

Comment: @KameshJungi In Block >> configure >> Only the listed pages, did you actually put the view name? That would not work.  You need to put **the path** to your view page here, NOT the view name.

Comment: I again tried my view path is www.website.com/our-services. So I tried to adding <our-services> , /our-services, our-services. But none of them is working

Answer (score 1):

There is a block_views module made specifically for this reason I believe.  It's in beta but works rather nicely for Drupal 7:

https://drupal.org/project/block_views

Cheers, 
-cs